# How to run two jobs simultaneously, each at least 10 times in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to begin the execution of job1 and job2 at the same time (e.g., ./job1 &; ./job2 &;) and re-execute a job immediately once it finishes. The whole task terminates when each job is executed at least 10 times. At the end of the script, I'd like to print out the execution time for each execution of both jobs. How can I do it in bash?

Comment: Your question would be much improved if you provided the code that you have already written, and asked about a specific part of the code that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that you cannot start two jobs at exactly the same time. One will start, and then the other will start. If you want to keep track of the status of a process, you will also need additional commands to run in the meantime. With that in mind, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Tested code works :)

tries1=0
tries2=0
minTries=10

pid1='null'
pid2='null'

while [[ $tries1 -lt $minTries || $tries2 -lt $minTries ]]
do
    if [[ ! -d "/proc/${pid1}" ]]
    then
        time ./job1 &
        pid1=$!
        tries1=$((tries1+1))
        echo "1 - $pid1 - $tries1"
    fi
    if [[ ! -d "/proc/${pid2}" ]]
    then
        time ./job2 &
        pid2=$!
        tries2=$((tries2+1))
        echo "2 - $pid2 - $tries2"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you restate the problem as "starting at (approximately) the same time, run ten instances of `job1` sequentially, and ten instances of `job2` sequentially, things are not so complicated.

```
run10 () {
    local i
    for i in $(seq 0 9); do
        "$1"
    done
}

run10 ./job1 & run10 ./job2
wait
```

There is no particular reason to put the second `run10` in the background, as we want to `wait` for the first one to finish at the end anyway.

I simply assume that `job1` and `job2` are wrappers which take care of collecting timing information in a suitable way.

Comment: The script should terminates when both job1 and job2 are executed for at least 10 times. So if job 2 runs much longer than job1, job1 should be executed more times than job2.